# How to covert this int to boolean?

Tags: java, integer, boolean

Im new to this and im having trouble with this error converting int to boolean.

```
public class HeadsOrTails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Heads = 0;
        int Tails = 0;
        
        for(long simulation = 1; simulation <= 2000000; simulation += 1)
        {
            int FlipResult = FlipCoin();
            if(FlipResult = 1)
            {
                Heads +=1;
            }
            else if(FlipResult = 0)
            {
                Tails += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Numer of heads appeared: " + Heads);
        System.out.println("Numer of tails appeared: " + Tails);
    }
    private static int FlipCoin() 
    {
        return (int) (Math.random() + 0.5);
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNiQm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVYw2.png)

Comment: you need to use `==` not `=` when comparing. Single `=` is for assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if condition use `==` operator, change your if condition to

```
if(FlipResult == 1){
    Heads +=1;
}
else if(FlipResult == 0){
    Tails += 1;
}
```

Currently you are trying to assign the value, which will give this error "int cannot be converted to boolean"

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` and `else if` conditions are missing another `=` in the code.
It should look something similar to this

```java
if (FlipResult==1) {
    //do Something
}
```

The single `=` means assigning a value to your variable, and the `==` means comparing values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic in if and else if statement

```
for(long simulation = 1; simulation <= 2000000; simulation += 1)
{
    int FlipResult = FlipCoin();
    if(FlipResult == 1)
    {
        Heads +=1;
    }
    else if(FlipResult == 0)
    {
        Tails += 1;
    }
}
```